# In Clojure how can I read a public member variables of an instance of a Java class?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure how can I read a public member variables of an instance of a Java class? I want something like:

```
 (. instance publicMemberName)
```

I also tried:

```
instance/publicMemberName
```

but this only works with static methods

Comment: Do you mean `(. member instance)` instead of `(. instance member)` ?

Comment: I meant (. instance member). Did you mean (.member instance) or (. member instance)? Anyway, thanks I have amended the question to make it more clear

Comment: Ugh, I did not know about the other form.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to get many or all of your publicMemberNames, you can convert a POJO into a Clojure map with (bean instance) which is nice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java, the class `java.awt.Point` has public fields `x` and `y`.  See the javadocs here http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html.

In Clojure the dot macro works for fields and methods.  This worked for me:

```
user=> (let [p (new java.awt.Point 2 4)] (.x p))
2
```

EDIT: The following also works (note the space between the dot and the p):

```
user=> (let [p (new java.awt.Point 2 4)] (. p x))
2
```

EDIT: I decided to make a complete example given that `java.awt.Point` has methods `getX` and `getY` in addition to public fields `x` and `y`.  So here goes.  First make a Java class like this:

```
public class C {
    public int x = 100;
}
```

Compile it

```
$ javac C.java
```

Now move `C.class` into your clojure directory.  Next start the REPL, import the class, and watch it work:

```
$ java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.2.0
user=> (import C)
C
user=> (let [q (new C)] (. q x))
100
```

Note the other way works too:

```
user=> (let [q (new C)] (.x q))
100
```

Comment: Would (. p x) work as well? With Java functions you can do (.fn instance) AND (. instance fn).

Comment: what if x in C is changing? as in clojure is added to a java project

Answer (score 2):

If your object follows Java bean convention of `getFoo` to access member field `foo`, and you only need read access (i.e. aren't going to be mutating your object), you can use `bean`.  That'll give you an immutable Clojure map that mimics the object, and then you can use standard keyword accessors.

```
user> (bean (java.awt.Point. 1.0 2.0))
{:y 2.0, :x 1.0, :location #<Point java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2]>, :class java.awt.Point}

user> (:x *1)
1.0
```