# How to write a public field of a Java object in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647020/in-clojure-how-can-i-read-a-public-member-variables-of-an-instance-of-a-java-cla) answers how to read a public field from a Java object:

```
(let [p (java.awt.Point.)]
  (.x p))  ; <- returns 0
```

I thought I could write the field in a similar way:

```
(let [p (java.awt.Point.)]
  (.x p 42))
```

But I get the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: x for class java.awt.Point
clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:53)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the [Clojure - Java Interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop):

> ```
> (set! (. instance-expr instanceFieldName-symbol) expr)
> ```
>
> Assignment special form.
>
> When the first operand is a field member access form, the assignment is to the corresponding field. If it is an instance field, the instance expr will be evaluated [and assigned to the corresponding instance field].

Also note the use of '-' in resolving a field:

> If the second operand [of `(. instance-expr member)`] is *a symbol starting with -, the member-symbol will resolve only as field access* (never as a 0-arity method) and *should be preferred* when that is the intent..."

Thus:

```
(set! (. p -x) 42)
```

Alternatively, the *"preferred idiomatic forms for accessing field or method members"* is slightly different, and this equivalency is shown in the macro expansion at the top of the page.

```
(set! (.-x p) 42)
```